1D FFT of 3D Eigen tensor along a specific direction
I have the following code in MATLAB where I am trying to reproduce in C++ using the FFTW library:
MATLAB code:
Nx = 8;  
Ny = 6; 
Nz= 8;
Lx =6;
Ly = 6;
xi_x =  (2*pi)/Lx;
yi_y =  (2*pi)/Ly;
xi  = ((0:Nx-1)/Nx)*(2*pi);
yi  = ((0:Ny-1)/Ny)*(2*pi);
x =  xi/xi_x;
y =  yi/yi_y;

zlow = 0;%a
zupp =6; %b
Lz = (zupp-zlow);
zgl = (1/2)*(((zupp-zlow)*zgl) + (zupp+zlow));
[X,Z,Y] = meshgrid(x,zgl,y);
%ICs
A = 2*pi / Lx;
B = 2*pi / Ly;
u = (Z-zlow) .* (Z-zupp) .* sin(A*X).* sin(B*Y);
%Take FFT along only X: 
uh =fft(u,[],2);
%Take FFT along only Y direction:
uh =fft(u,[],3); %since meshgrid(x,z,y) then #3 is Y direction

I am able to get the correct results in C++ for the X direction only so:
uh =fft(u,[],2);

which is:
fftw_plan const the_plan = fftw_plan_many_dft_r2c(
1,  //rank-one transforms
&nx, 
(nz+1), //one transform per row
Tensor2D.data(), //extract 2D matrix out of 3D tensor
nullptr,
1,
reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(Tensor2DK.data()), //output
nullptr,
(nz+1),
1,
FFTW_MEASURE);

Where I define a 3D Tensor and extract a 2D matrix as the following:
static const int nx = 8; 
static const int ny = 6;  
static const int nz = 8; 

Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> uFun((nz+1),nx,ny);   //tensor(row,col,matrix)
uFun.setZero();

Eigen::Tensor<double, 2> Tensor2D((nz+1),nx,ny); 
Eigen::Tensor<double, 2> Tensor2DK((nz+1),nx,ny); 

Tensor2D = uFun.slice(std::array{0,0,1}, std::array{nz+1,nx,1}.reshape(std::array{nz+1,nx});

//Take FFT
fftw_excute(the_plan);

Above code returns correct results of uh =fft(u,[],2);
However, I am really unable to take the 1D FFT along only Y similarly as uh =fft(u,[],3); I keep getting results that don't match MATLAB. How can I fix this?
EDIT:
I have simplified my problem more by testing a 2D matrix first since my main issues is I am unable to take the 1D FFT of a 2D matrix along each row using FFTW library. I have a simple MATLAB code that I am using to benchmark my results and it looks like:
Nx=8;
Ny=8;
u = eye(Ny+1,Nx); %very simple choice for now, returns ny+1 rows by nx columns
%take FFT along columns
urow = fft(u,[],1);
ucol = fft(u,[],2); 

Now, in C++ I have tried the following:

Take 1D FFT of column-major 2D matrix along each column (this works)

#include "fftw3.h"
#include<unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

static const int nx=8;
static const int ny=8;

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
int main{

Eigen::MatrixXd u(ny+1,nx);
u.setIdentity();
Eigen::MatrixXcd uOut(ny+1,nx);
//1D FFT along cols
fftw_plan const fwd = fftw_plan_many_dft_r2c(
1,
&nx,
u.data(),
nullptr,
(ny+1),
1,
reinterpert_cast<fftw_complex*>(uOut.data()),
nullptr,
(ny+1),
1,
FFTW_MEASURE);
fftw_excute(fwd);
std::cout<<uOut<<endl; //this is correct
}

The above code is correct and returns a result that matches MATLAB: ucol = fft(u,[],2); and output is:
ucol =

   1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.7071 - 0.7071i   0.0000 - 1.0000i  -0.7071 - 0.7071i  -1.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.7071 + 0.7071i   0.0000 + 1.0000i   0.7071 + 0.7071i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 1.0000i  -1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 1.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 1.0000i  -1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 1.0000i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.7071 - 0.7071i   0.0000 + 1.0000i   0.7071 - 0.7071i  -1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.7071 + 0.7071i   0.0000 - 1.0000i  -0.7071 + 0.7071i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -1.0000 + 0.0000i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.7071 + 0.7071i   0.0000 - 1.0000i   0.7071 + 0.7071i  -1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.7071 - 0.7071i   0.0000 + 1.0000i  -0.7071 - 0.7071i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 1.0000i  -1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 1.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 1.0000i  -1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 1.0000i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.7071 + 0.7071i   0.0000 + 1.0000i  -0.7071 + 0.7071i  -1.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.7071 - 0.7071i   0.0000 - 1.0000i   0.7071 - 0.7071i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i


Take 1D FFT of column-major 2D matrix along each row (INCORRECT) following with this post: How do I use fftw_plan_many_dft on a transposed array of data?
where they said: // ... if data is column-major, set istride=howmany, idist=1 //    if data is row-major, set istride=1, idist=N

Eigen::MatrixXd u(ny+1,nx);
u.setIdentity();
Eigen::MatrixXcd uOut(ny+1,nx);
//1D FFT along rows by:
// if data is row-major, set istride=1, idist=N
fftw_plan const fwd = fftw_plan_many_dft_r2c(
1,
&nx,
(ny+1),
u.data(),
nullptr,
1, //istride=1
nx, //idist=N
reinterpert_cast<fftw_complex*>(uOut.data()),
nullptr,
(ny+1),
1,
FFTW_MEASURE);
fftw_excute(fwd);
std::cout<<uOut<<endl; //this is incorrect
}

Above code does NOT work and return only zeros.

Convert original column-major 2D matrix to a row-major matrix instead and repeat (1) (also does NOT work)

Eigen::MatrixXd u(ny+1,nx);
u.setIdentity();
urow = u.transpose(); //row-major 2D matrix 
Eigen::MatrixXcd uOutrow(ny+1,nx);
fftw_plan const fwd = fftw_plan_many_dft_r2c(
1,
&nx,
urow.data(),
nullptr,
(ny+1),
1,
reinterpert_cast<fftw_complex*>(uOutrow.data()),
nullptr,
(ny+1),
1,
FFTW_MEASURE);
fftw_excute(fwd);
std::cout<<uOut<<endl; //this is incorrect
}

Above code does NOT work either. I am SO confused with what seems to be a simple task. The FFTW library documentation is so difficult to understand with no examples and so I am left even more confused. I think I would like to focus on my edit and get help with the 2D matrix only since it'd be straightforward to implement with tensors once I get it working.
What am I doing wrong? How can I take a simple 1D FFT along each row such as urow=fft(u,[],1); and the correct output should look like:
urow =

   1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.7660 - 0.6428i   0.1736 - 0.9848i  -0.5000 - 0.8660i  -0.9397 - 0.3420i  -0.9397 + 0.3420i  -0.5000 + 0.8660i   0.1736 + 0.9848i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.1736 - 0.9848i  -0.9397 - 0.3420i  -0.5000 + 0.8660i   0.7660 + 0.6428i   0.7660 - 0.6428i  -0.5000 - 0.8660i  -0.9397 + 0.3420i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.5000 - 0.8660i  -0.5000 + 0.8660i   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.5000 - 0.8660i  -0.5000 + 0.8660i   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.5000 - 0.8660i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.9397 - 0.3420i   0.7660 + 0.6428i  -0.5000 - 0.8660i   0.1736 + 0.9848i   0.1736 - 0.9848i  -0.5000 + 0.8660i   0.7660 - 0.6428i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.9397 + 0.3420i   0.7660 - 0.6428i  -0.5000 + 0.8660i   0.1736 - 0.9848i   0.1736 + 0.9848i  -0.5000 - 0.8660i   0.7660 + 0.6428i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.5000 + 0.8660i  -0.5000 - 0.8660i   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.5000 + 0.8660i  -0.5000 - 0.8660i   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.5000 + 0.8660i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.1736 + 0.9848i  -0.9397 + 0.3420i  -0.5000 - 0.8660i   0.7660 - 0.6428i   0.7660 + 0.6428i  -0.5000 + 0.8660i  -0.9397 - 0.3420i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.7660 + 0.6428i   0.1736 + 0.9848i  -0.5000 + 0.8660i  -0.9397 + 0.3420i  -0.9397 - 0.3420i  -0.5000 - 0.8660i   0.1736 - 0.9848i


I think that this link FFTW advanced complex FFTs almost describes what you want to do. You might want to try this variant first to get the hang of the indexing and terminology (even though you ultimately want to use to real to complex conjugate symmetric forms. I think that the correct invocation might be fftw_plan const fwd = fftw_plan_many_dft_r2c(
1,
&nx, ny,
urow.data(),
nullptr,
1,
1,
reinterpert_cast<fftw_complex*>(uOutrow.data()),
nullptr,
1,
1,
FFTW_MEASURE);  but I haven't tested it. BTW output will be nx+1 cmplx.

@MartinBrown I attempted what you suggested but for some reason it's not working really just returning zeros.
